# Simultaneous triangulation and Jordan normal form of commuting nilpotent matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nilpotent-matrices

Let $A_1,\ldots,A_r$ be $n\times n$ nilpotent matrices over $\mathbb C$, the field of complex numbers, satisfying $A_i\cdot A_j=A_j\cdot A_i$ for all $i,j$. As the matrices commute, they admit simultaneous triangulation. But I want to bring $A_1$ into Jordan normal form. Recall that a nilpotent matrix $N\in M_n(\mathbb C)$ is said to be in Jordan normal form if all nonzero entries of $N$ are equal to $1$ and every nonzero entry of $N$ lies on the super diagonal. My question is does there exist an invertible matrix $B\in M_n(\mathbb C)$ such that $B^{-1}A_iB$ is upper triangular for all $i=1,\ldots,n$ and $B^{-1}A_1B$ is in Jordan normal form?

Comment: They can be brought into Jordan Normal Form simultaneously. When you look at the proof og the JNF Theorem, you see that all data you use are preserved by any matrix which commutes with the given matrix.

Comment: @Echo what do you mean? take $r=2$, $A_1\neq 0$, $A_2=A_1^2$.

Comment: This is best understood from the viewpoint of representation theory. Let $\mathcal A$ be the subalgebra of $\mathbb C^{n\times n}$ generated by the $r$ matrices. Since these matrices are nilpotent and commute, this algebra $\mathcal A$ is a finite-dimensional local ring (i.e., it is commutative and has a unique maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ with $\mathcal A / \mathfrak{m} \cong \mathbb C$). This yields that all simple $\mathcal A$-modules are isomorphic to $\mathbb C$. Hence, the Jordan-Hölder filtration of $\mathbb C^n$ as an $\mathcal A$-module has subquotients ...

Comment: ... isomorphic to $\mathbb C$. In other words, it is a complete flag preserved by all your matrices. Now take any basis of this flag (i.e., a basis of $\mathbb C^n$ compatible with it), and observe that the matrices $A_i$ are triangular with respect to this basis. Alas, I don't know where this is explained in a readable way without too much overkill.

Comment: @ M.G. Sorry, I could not understand the relation of your comment to my question. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @ darij If i'm correct, simultaneous triangulation follow from your argument. Does it also imply that $A_1$ attains Jordon normal form with respect to this basis?

Comment: @sagnikchakraborty Oh, apologies! I have misread that you want all $B^{-1} A_i B$ to be in Jordan normal form rather than only $B^{-1} A_1 B$. This makes my comments moot. Please disregard, unless you actually mean $B^{-1} A_i B$.